# Larvel 8 :- Array to string conversion

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

I get the title error [image] when I run command: **php artisan db:seed**. I want to store data in database. migration is already don. but when seeding it shows and error. I have no idea where this problem comes from.

**ProductFactory.php**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Product::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->word,
            'detail' => $this->faker->paragraphs,
            'price' => $this->faker->numberBetween(100, 1000),
            'stock' => $this->faker->randomDigit(),
            'discount' => $this->faker->numberBetween(2, 30),
        ];
    }
}
```

**DatabaseSeeder.php**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // \App\Models\User::factory(10)->create();
        \App\Models\Product::factory(50)->create();
       
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the exact error? it should point you in the right direction. I cant see anything wrong on first sight

Comment: @Flame i edit the question please check the screen shot

Comment: `dd($var)` the array from the `definition()` function, it appears to contain an array? Or it happens later on in the process where `updated_at`/`created_at` are added into the object.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
'detail' => $this->faker->paragraph,
```

instead of

```
'detail' => $this->faker->paragraphs,
```

Answer (score 0):

`$this->faker->paragraphs()` and `$this->faker->words` accepts two arguments optionally, the number of paragraphs and words, and a boolean for whether or not to return as an array or string

Use this

```
'detail' => $this->faker->paragraph,
```

In place of:

```
'detail' => $this->faker->paragraphs,
```